# How to select data from dataframe and create a subdataset?

Tags: r, select, merge

I have 2 dataframe in R. "X" dataframe has 2 columns (number of identity[ID] of the animal "i" in the 1st, and in the 2nd col. the point related of this animal "i"), and "n"-rows that is the number of animals that I scored. The "Y" dataframe has 2 col. as well as X (ID of the animal "i" in the 1st col. and in the 2nd col. the point related to the animal "i" in the same row, but for another caracther that I studied). Not all the animals have both the evaluations, but only some of them. I would like to take a sub-dataframe with only the animals that have both the evaluations. I would like to use the ID to recognize which animals have both evaluations.
The subdaframe that I would like to make is composed by 3 columns: ID of the "i" animal (in the 1st c.), point that was in dataframe X (in the 2nd c.), and point that was in dataframe Y for animal "i" (in the 3rd c.). I'm quite new in R and I search on web. I found "merge" but it's seems not work. Could you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide reproducible example so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I did a subdataframe of what each dataframe with only the 4° and the 11° column, and then I used this script:
a=merge(x,y,by.x="V4",by.x="V4")